# SSRS refresh default value for parameter with no defined available values

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, default

I am creating a report in SSRS which displays information about properties in a county. The user can select a district for which to view properties. Some districts are small, having only 10 properties, others are large with close to 8000 properties. For the large properties, the System.OutOfMemory exception gets thrown when trying to run the report. To work around this, I added 2 parameters where the users can specify the range of properties to look at (1-500, 7-2231, etc). The default values for these parameters are 1 and the count of properties, so that all properties are reported by default.

The problem I'm having is that after you select a district and the parameters are populated based on that district, if you then change your district, the default values don't change. So if the first district you select has only 10 properties and the second one has 500, you'll only see the first 10 in the second district. I've done some research to see if it's possible to refresh the default, but all the solutions I've seen are using dropdown parameters, which is impractical for what I'm doing. Is it possible to refresh the default values of a non-dropdown parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible in the way you're asking for.  A workaround would be to give the user a parameter to choose between "use defaults" and "use entered values", and then don't put defaults in the other parameters.  If the users understand what they'll get if they use defaults, this will work the same way, though it's a bit more confusing.

In your dataset, you'd have to have an OR or CASE that tested the value of the @default parameter to determine whether to use entered parameters or defaults.